# Thinking Sphinx with Rails: should I include these files in my git push?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm getting a lot of untracked / modified files that are like this in my Rails app:

```
db/sphinx/development/user_core.spa
db/sphinx/development/user_core.spd
db/sphinx/development/book_core.sph
db/sphinx/development/book_core.spi
db/sphinx/development/book_core.spp
db/sphinx/development/book_core.sps
```

etc.

Should I include these when I commit and push in git, or should I put db/sphinx/development/* in my .gitignore file?

--EDIT after getting answer below--

I ended up adding this to my .gitignore file...

```
# Ignore certain Sphinx files
/db/sphinx/*
/config/*.sphinx.conf
```

...and then doing what is recommended here: [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add those to .gitignore. They're similar to database files. The only sphinx specific file I think you might want to check in is the `config/sphinx.yml` files, assuming it doesn't contain any sensitive information.